# Slow SQL query (multiple selects and LIMIT 1 in each one)

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

mysql-nodejs is slower than executing an sql query directly in phpMyAdmin, However, I need to optimize this query because it's now taking 10sec.
I think that it's performing searches for every row in g which is taking too much time.

This is the query I tried

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate) 
        FROM   tbl1 
        WHERE  txt = g.txt 
               AND keyword = g.keyword 
               AND user = g.user 
               AND coldate < g.coldate 
        ORDER  BY coldate DESC 
        LIMIT  1) AS LastOneBefore, 
       (SELECT Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate) 
        FROM   tbl1 
        WHERE  txt = g.txt 
               AND keyword = g.keyword 
               AND user = g.user 
               AND coldate < ( Now() - INTERVAL 7 day ) 
        ORDER  BY coldate DESC 
        LIMIT  1) AS LastOneBefore7days, 
       (SELECT Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate) 
        FROM   tbl1 
        WHERE  txt = g.txt 
               AND keyword = g.keyword 
               AND user = g.user 
               AND coldate < ( Now() - INTERVAL 30 day ) 
        ORDER  BY coldate 
        LIMIT  1) AS LastOneBefore30days 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   tbl1 
                WHERE  txt = "txt1" 
                       AND user = "user1" 
                ORDER  BY coldate DESC) k 
        GROUP  BY txt, 
                  keyword) g
```

can it be optimized to take less execution time?

tbl1 Columns:
id(int) , user (varchar) , coldate (Date) , txt (varchar) , keyword (varchar) , col1 (int)

Example of Data:

```
id      user    coldate     txt     keyword     col1
1       usr1    23/07/2019  txt1    kwd1        1000
2       usr1    20/07/2019  txt1    kwd1        1100
3       usr1    12/07/2019  txt1    kwd1        900
4       usr1    23/07/2019  txt1    kwd2        10100
5       usr1    23/07/2019  txt2    kwd1        1000
6       usr1    23/07/2019  txt2    kwd2        1000
7       usr1    20/06/2019  txt2    kwd2        1000
```

so I need to output a row for each group with same kwd and txt like this

```
id      user    coldate     txt     keyword     col1   LastOneBefore                LastOneBefore7days          LastOneBefore30days
1       usr1    23/07/2019  txt1    kwd1        1000   1100 at 20/07/2019           900 at 12/07/20194                  null
4       usr1    23/07/2019  txt1    kwd2        10100   null                            null                            null
6       usr1    23/07/2019  txt2    kwd2        1000    1000 at 20/06/2019            null                          1000 at 20/06/2019
```

Comment: Will you please provide table data? so I can manage your query easily
Thank you

Comment: This really looks like one of the cases where doing separate queries is going to be faster

Comment: How to separate these queries?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "how to separate" them, they're already 3 distinct queries, you can just run them and return an object which properties are the records that you need, right?

Comment: @AbderrahmanMamas . . . `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` just doesn't make sense and your query would not run on a recent version of MySQL using default settings.  You should probably ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but these are not "distinct" queries, as you can see here " txt = g.txt 
               AND keyword = g.keyword 
               AND user = g.user 
               AND coldate < g.coldate "

Results of each query are dependable of the  **g** Select

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have the latest version of MySQL and it's running correctly and as desired..
I'll show in the post a clearer example.

Comment: @AbderrahmanMamas They're distinct in the sense that the value of `LastOneBefore` doesn't depend on the value of `LastOneBefore30days` or on the value of `LastOneBefore7days`. So you can get these three values as three separate queries

Comment: Yes true, but I don't know how to store a query results and make another query on it with nodejs or mysql,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to RUN this query in your code

I hope it'll give you output as expected and give update to me so I can give expected solution to you

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
WHEN  coldate < g.coldate  THEN  Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate)
ELSE 0 END AS LastOneBefore,
CASE
WHEN coldate < ( Now() - INTERVAL 7 day )  THEN Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate)
ELSE 0 END AS LastOneBefore7days,
CASE
WHEN coldate < ( Now() - INTERVAL 30 day ) THEN Concat(col1, ' AT ', coldate)
ELSE 0 END AS LastOneBefore30days

FROM   
(
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   tbl1 
                WHERE  txt = "txt1" 
                       AND user = "user1" 
                ORDER  BY coldate DESC) k 
        GROUP  BY txt, 
                  keyword
) g 
WHERE   txt = g.txt           
AND keyword = g.keyword 
AND user = g.user
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it's not the desired result, I'll try to explain more..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get these columns (LastOneBefore7days, LastOneBefore30days) this way but still can't get LastOneBefore

```
SELECT *, 'Latest' as Type FROM (  SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE  txt="txt1"  AND User="usr1"    Order by coldate DESC ) k GROUP BY txt,keyword
UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'Before30Days' as Type FROM (  SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE      txt="txt1"  AND User="usr1"  AND coldate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)   Order by coldate DESC ) k GROUP BY txt,keyword

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'Before7Days' as Type FROM (  SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE  txt="txt1"  AND User="usr1"  AND coldate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)   Order by coldate DESC ) k GROUP BY txt,keyword
```

Comment: I found ho to get LastOneBefore using a linear SQL statement here http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group
Thank you all for your time